# variable with spaces in plotly

Tags: python, charts, plotly, plotly-express, variable-names

I know it is not ideal to have variable names with spaces. But I am curious if there is a way to do this for plotly in python easily.

So this worked for variables without spaces:

```
fig_gender = px.bar(
    df_gender_grp, y="gender", x="index", 
    color="gender",
    labels=dict(gender="gender", index="count"),
```

but the same approach for variables with spaces (e.g., age group) did not work:

```
fig_age_grp = px.bar(
   df_age_grp, y="gender", x="index", 
   color="age group",
   labels=dict(df_age_grp.(age group)="age group", index="count")
```

I tried using the f-string as well as df.variable name approaches, but both did not work. The error message is "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Thank you.

Comment: do u want this only because of labels ?

Comment: yes, and no. I know how to redo the labels, but I am curious how it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `labels=...` you map column names of your dataframe to text to be displayed in the legend or at the axes.

In your case, it seems that you want column `age group` to displayed as text `age group` (which would happen anyway) and column `index` to be displayed as `count`.

Try:

`labels={"age group": "age group", "index": "count"}`

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem, it is likely that plotly allows for `{"age group": "age group", "index": "count"}` as a valid argument for `labels` (I cannot test this since you do not provide a minimum reproducible example).

In your code snippet, you are passing `dict(df_age_grp.(age group)="age group", index="count")` as a value to parameter `label`. That is wrong for three reasons. First, [`plotly.express.bar`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar) expects a dictionary with string keys (name of the column) and string values (label for the variable). Instead, you seem to attempt to pass a *Pandas series* as a dictionary key. Second, in general, a series is not a permitted dictionary key because it is not hashable. Third, your method of accessing column `age group` is not allowed. This method is called [attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access), but it is only available for columns that have a [valid Python identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) - that is, `age group` is not valid. While spaces in column names are indeed allowed, they are not attribute-accessible and you would have to resort to, e.g., `df_age_grp['age group']` (however, not here in this case as explained before).

Comment: so there is no way access attributes for variable with spaces?

Comment: It is not me, in case you are wondering. My guess - it does not answer the question with a solution (in an earlier version of your answer). But I appreciate you were unpacking the reason why the problem. stackoverflow can be an impatient place. You were right that "plotly allows for {"age group": "age group"} as a valid argument". Thank you.